# Spring Caching support for i18n services

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using `@Cachable` annotation support from Spring to speed up the retrieval of some data provided by the Services.

Some of my Services' calls rely on the `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` method to retrieve for example the `Locale` attached to the current Thread.

The content returned by those services is Internationalized but the `Locale` is not part of the signature of my Service methods so it doesn't contribute as a param to the Key generation mechanism for the caching solution.

Of course not all Service calls have to support i18n, so the cached data and key generation can be Locale agnostic in those cases.

Is there a fast way to alter the key generation for those specific service methods that are using `LocaleContextHolder` functionalities to return i18n content?

I saw the generic `KeyGenerator` interface used to create the key but this would affect all service calls caching the same data more times if the service is not using internationalization.

should I simply override the key generation and for example append the locale to my params like?

```
@Cacheable(value = "someName", key = "#p0.concat('-').concat(T(org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder).getLocale().toLanguageTag())")
```

this solution has problems when I need to evict things from the cache as I can't use `@CacheEvict` with wildcards like with `key="p0.concat('-*')"` to match all localized instances that are cached

any suggestion would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your case I would suggest to use keyGenerator instead of key attribute with SpEL expression. Like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName",  keyGenerator="localizedGenerator")
```

First of all this will abstract key generation away from static method invocation, second of all, you can use the keyGenerator to perofm evict oprerations based on locale and other parameters if needed. KeyGenerator is flexible enough and provides access to all runtime data, so you can figure out if and when a localized resource is accessed

```
@CacheEvict (value = "cacheName",  keyGenerator="localizedGenerator")
```

some basic samples can be seen in doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html